# Get column data without using table name at the beginning

Tags: r, function, dataframe

For example if the table name is "my.data" and I want to reach the column `age` I need to write `my.data$age`.
Is there any function that can "remember" the name of the table?
In case i want to get the age column I only will need to write `age`.

It's use mainly when I enter fields to a formula, and sometimes the tables name are long and its hard to read it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if I told you that few data sets could have same column names? What if I told you that you that a data set can have the same name as another data sets column name? Don't be lazy, play safe **and don't use `attach` at any circumstances**.

Comment: I agree with @DavidArenburg, however it is still good to know that there is a function for it in R.

Comment: Please show us an example case as there are various solutions to help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `with` could be of use here. For example:

```
with(mtcars, paste(mpg, hp, carb, disp, sep="_"))
```

saves you from typing out `mtcars` 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `attach()` function. For example:

```
attach(mtcars)
hist(cyl)
```

This code produces a histogram of the cyl column of the mtcars dataset.

Comment: Note, however that if you change the column cyl in the dataframe mtcars, the attached column cyl is not updated unless you detach re-attach it.

Comment: I don't want to vote this down, because it's technically a correct answer, but I cannot urge you strongly enough to stay away from `attach()`. @Joe 's answer of `with()` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Forward pipes (`%>%`) and `tidyverse` functions are often the way to go:

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- df %<%
  select(col_a, col_b) %>%
  mutate(col_c = col_a + col_b)
```

Etc.

The first line is assigning your changes to a new object (it just so happens I'm writing over `df`, but you could use something else) and specifying which data frame to work on. You don't need to specify these again, even if your chains are hundreds of lines long.